# Magento - MySQL error while loading an admin panel page

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I am receiving the following error:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:2328:"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sales_flat_order.web4pro_abandonedcart_flag' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT `main_table`.*, `sales_flat_order`.`web4pro_abandonedcart_flag`, GROUP_CONCAT(order_item_tbl.`name` SEPARATOR '\n') AS `product_names`, GROUP_CONCAT(order_item_tbl.`sku` SEPARATOR '\n') AS `skus`, GROUP_CONCAT(order_item_tbl.`product_id` SEPARATOR '\n') AS `product_ids`, GROUP_CONCAT(order_item_tbl.`product_options` SEPARATOR '^') AS `product_options`, `order_address_billing_tbl`.`company` AS `billing_company`, `order_address_billing_tbl`.`street` AS `billing_street`, `order_address_billing_tbl`.`city` AS `billing_city`, `order_address_billing_tbl`.`region` AS `billing_region`, `order_address_billing_tbl`.`country_id` AS `billing_country_id`, `order_address_billing_tbl`.`postcode` AS `billing_postcode`, `order_address_billing_tbl`.`telephone` AS `billing_telephone`, `order_address_shipping_tbl`.`company` AS `shipping_company`, `order_address_shipping_tbl`.`street` AS `shipping_street`, `order_address_shipping_tbl`.`city` AS `shipping_city`, `order_address_shipping_tbl`.`region` AS `shipping_region`, `order_address_shipping_tbl`.`country_id` AS `shipping_country_id`, `order_address_shipping_tbl`.`postcode` AS `shipping_postcode`, `order_address_shipping_tbl`.`telephone` AS `shipping_telephone`, `order_payment_tbl`.`method` FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order` ON main_table.increment_id = sales_flat_order.increment_id
 LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_order_item` AS `order_item_tbl` ON `order_item_tbl`.`order_id` = `main_table`.`entity_id` AND `order_item_tbl`.`parent_item_id` IS NULL
 LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_order_address` AS `order_address_billing_tbl` ON order_address_billing_tbl.parent_id = main_table.entity_id AND order_address_billing_tbl.`address_type` = "billing"
 LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_order_address` AS `order_address_shipping_tbl` ON order_address_shipping_tbl.parent_id = main_table.entity_id AND order_address_shipping_tbl.`address_type` = "shipping"
 LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_order_payment` AS `order_payment_tbl` ON order_payment_tbl.parent_id = main_table.entity_id GROUP BY `main_table`.`entity_id`) AS `main_table` WHERE (`sales_flat_order`.`web4pro_abandonedcart_flag` = 1) AND (order_group_id = '0')";i:1;s:5789:"#0 /home/*********/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
```

If i get it right it is not finding `web4pro_abandonedcart_flag` column in `sales_flat_order` table right ?

However i have checked and i am 100% sure that there is such column in that table.

Here is the function which creates this malfunction:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_grid_collection');
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    $sales_flat_order_table = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales_flat_order');
    $collection->getSelect()->join($sales_flat_order_table , 'main_table.increment_id = '.$sales_flat_order_table.'.increment_id', 'web4pro_abandonedcart_flag');
    $collection->addFieldToFilter($sales_flat_order_table.'.web4pro_abandonedcart_flag',array('eq' => 1));
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

Can you please advice where the problem can be ?

Comment: Yep, you interpret the error message correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the given field may exist in the given table, however, the `sales_flat_order` table is not referenced in the outer query's `from` clause, yet in the `where` criteria you are referencing a field from this table.

Your query in a simplified way looks like below:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (...) AS `main_table`
WHERE (`sales_flat_order`.`web4pro_abandonedcart_flag` = 1) AND (order_group_id = '0')
```

In the outer query either remove `sales_flat_order` from the field name, or replace it by `main_table`. But the best solution would be to get rid of the subquery completely.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid answer, but how am i supposed to find the file where this query is written ? Kind regards.

Comment: I'm sorry, but 1) this is a different question from what you have asked 2) even if I wanted to answer this question, I would not be, since there is nothing in your question that would indicate the place of the error. You have to check out your error logs. If this query is an auto-generated one to determine the record count returned by the query, then you potentially face a bug.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. I have included the function which is making the query, but i am not sure how to fix it. Can you please check it out once again. Thank you.

Comment: Pls do not edit your question to ask sg different. Close the current question and ask any subsequent questions you have in their own posts.

Comment: I have resolved the problem. Thank you so much for the help.